# How to dynamically resize webpage layout according to window size?

Tags: css, html, layout, resize

I am relatively new to web development, I am wondering if anyones knows off hand a simple solution to making the page I have under development dynamically resize to the window size without distorting the layout. I would also like to try to have the page centered as well, the problem is I tried centering it but as I resized the window the elements on the page moved out of place. Any help is appreciated.

I went ahead and put the code up onto a server so it can easily be viewed I did this mainly for testing. The project is voluntary and will eventually be used as  part of a language education tool. I am just trying to get the layout so that it will resize dynamically without distorting the layout.

With the current setup I have to manually zoom out if the screen resolution is low to get the layout to fit properly within the screen.

I am currently using absolute positioning in CSS to position the page elements relative to the background image, they need to be positioned properly to fit into the background pattern.

The page can be viewed at http://www.kapacitive.com/Main_Page_Template.html will have to view the page source to view the code.

Once again any help is appreciated and please if you do not have something helpful to say please just don't even respond. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To achieve a somewhat dynamic layout, you can use CSS3 media queries:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  foo {
    ...
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  foo {
    ...
  }
}
```

They target specific screen sizes.

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion. This looks like it holds a lot of potential and current browsers support the feature.

I just wonder how I could go about quickly and easily testing between various screen sizes using a single machine.

Comment: Resize your browser window ;)

Comment: Ha, I wouldn't know the size the window is though, probably a way to quickly find it using javascript.

Also, with this method only the window size is taken into account is there a way to also take into account screen resolution or some standard rule of thumb used by the wizards?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the width on the body and set these styles to your main Nav Cubes:

```
#mainNavCubes {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 170px;
  margin-left: -240px;
}
```

This will set their position to the middle of the screen and with the negative margin you can push them to the left.

Comment: I would add that the same thing should probably be applied to the vertical positioning for true centering, and that body should have `min-width` set to keep things from spilling off the top and left edges of the screen.

Comment: The `min-width` on the body makes sense, otherwise the containers overlap and the vertical positioning is good, too. I just wanted to show a start.

Comment: The issue with this, which I had ran into previously, is that the MainNavCubes moves independently of the background and it should be aligned with the background design.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can possition the background, too. Like this: `background-position: 50% 50%`. You should be able to align the cubes  with some trial and error

Comment: It still goes out of alignment with resizes, not as badly though.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the Web Developer extension for either Firefox or Chrome
Check following link:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm
 very useful for measuring both window and viewport size. It also allows you to set the window size according to a few default sizes.

(It has a whole load of other useful web dev tools as well.)